# best lucene query for user search input

Tags: c#, java, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have news storage with 1,000,000 records Im using lucene library for fulltext searching my news hast (title, body, news date, ...) i need to find the best query for finding most relevant results from user input what strategy or algorithm i should use for achieve this

now im using something like this (title^3.0 body^2.0) but i think its to simple i'm searching for more sophisticated algorithm to get more relevant results.

I really really appreciate if you help me finding that my overflow friends !

Answer (score 0):

Improving search relevance takes time and iterative refinement.

The LucidImagination team have a good write up (very solr based though):
http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Search-Application-Relevance-Issues

You may want to analyse logs and add pageviews per doc into your index so you can factor that in your sort order.

The figures don't have to be really accurate as long as magnitude variations are captured.

You should also analyse logs for mis-spellings. The lucidimagination guys had some a podcast or blog about indexing them as well.